# Finding set difference between two complex dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x, python

I have two dictionaries of the following structure:

```
a) dict1 = {'a':[ [1,2], [3,4] ], 'b':[ [1,2],[5,6] ]}
b) dict2 = {'a':[ [1,2], [5,6] ], 'b':[ [1,2],[7,8] ]}
```

I need to find the set difference between each key in the dictionary i.e., dict1['a'] - dict2['a'] should return [3,4]. Any thought is appreciated.

Comment: What should happen for `dict1 = {'c': [[1, 2], [3, 4]]}; dict2 = {'c':[[5, 6], [7, 8]]}` ?

Comment: It should return dict1['c'] = [ [1,2], [3,4] ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got the wrong data structure for what you're trying to do.

Use this instead.

```
dict1 = {'a': [(1, 2), (3, 4)], 'b': [(1, 2), (5, 6)]}
dict2 = {'a': [(1, 2), (5, 6)], 'b': [(1, 2), (7, 8)]}
```

Life is simpler when you try to do set operations on immutable objects like tuples.

This will transform your list-of-lists into a list-of-tuples.

```
>>> dict( (key,[tuple(v) for v in dict1[key]]) for key in dict1 )
{'a': [(1, 2), (3, 4)], 'b': [(1, 2), (5, 6)]}
```

Here's the complete solution.

```
>>> dict1t= dict( (key,[tuple(v) for v in dict1[key]]) for key in dict1 )
>>> dict2t= dict( (key,[tuple(v) for v in dict2[key]]) for key in dict2 )
>>> set(dict1t['a'])-set(dict2t['a'])
set([(3, 4)])
```

Answer (score 6):

The use of mutable items (such as lists) makes the problem MUCH harder, as it precludes the simple use of Python's `set` data structure. It may be worth making temporary copies/versions which actually use tuples in lieu of those pesky lists:

```
def tempaux(d):
  return dict((k, set(tuple(x) for x in v))
              for k, v in d.iteritems())
```

Now:

```
def thedifs(dd1, dd2)
  d1 = tempaux(dd1)
  d2 = tempaux(dd2)
  allkeys = set(d1).update(d2)
  empty = set()
  difs = []
  for k in allkeys:
    s1 = d1.get(k, empty)
    s2 = d2.get(k, empty)
    adif = s1 - s2
    if adif: difs.append(adif)
  return difs
```

This assumes actual set difference rather than symmetric difference etc. You can of course turn back the tuples into lists before returns, &c, depending on your exact requirements.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> s1 = set([(1,2), (3,4)])
>>> s2 = set([(1,2), (5,6)])
>>> s1 - s2
{(3, 4)}
```

Answer (score 2):

## applicable to list or dict or number when a and b share the same structure

```
c={'a':'1','b':'2'}
d={'a':'10','b':'20'}
e={'x':c,'t':15}
f={'x':d,'t':19}

def diff(a,b):
    if isinstance(a, int) and isinstance(b, int):
        b = b - a
        return b
    if isinstance(a, str) and isinstance(b, str):
        if a.isdigit() and b.isdigit():
            b = str(int(b) - int(a))
            return b
        else:
            b = a
            return b
    if type(a) is list and type(b) is list:
        for i in range(len(a)):
            b[i] = diff(a[i],b[i])
        return b
    if type(a) is dict and type(b) is dict:
        for k,v in b.iteritems():
            b[k] = diff(a[k],b[k])
        return b

print diff(e,f)
```