# Code and render dictionary list - each key is element of a set, value is difference between two sets

Tags: python, django, dictionary, set, iteration

The example below perfectly articulates my problem.

My models are:

**person**

```
id  name
1   Alf
2   Beauty
```

**fruit**

```
id  name
1   apple
2   banana
3   cape gooseberry
4   date
5   eggplant
```

**diet**

```
id  person  fruit
1   Alf apple
2   Beauty  apple
3   Alf banana
4   Beauty  cape gooseberry
5   Alf date
6   Beauty  eggplant
7   Alf eggplant
8   Alf apple
9   Beauty  apple
10  Alf banana
11  Beauty  cape gooseberry
```

(Of course, the person and fruit in the Diet model are actually foreign keys in the background.)

**Required**

Any of the people did not have the full fruit diet?

If so, output = dictionary list, the respective key/values pairs being such person and the missing fruit from his/her diet

If not, output = "None"

**My thinking**

```py
persons = set(Person.objects.values_list('name', flat=True).order_by('name'))
available_fruit = set(Fruit.objects.values_list('name', flat=True).order_by('name'))
fruit_in_diet = set(Diet.objects.filter(person_id=1).values_list('fruit_id', flat=True).order_by('fruit_id'))
missing_fruit = available_fruit - fruit_in_diet
```

**Done**

Tested my thinking and it works, for both persons respectively - that is, individually.
It works only in so far as I get a set consisting of the correct `missing_fruits` for each person used in the code.

**My questions**

- How do I get a dictionary list as output?
- How do I get a single dictionary list for both persons?
  *In other words, how do I iterate over keys consisting of set elements AND values consisting of set differences?*
- How do I render that dictionary list on HTML?

The only related help I could find is [Finding set difference between two complex dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358101/finding-set-difference-between-two-complex-dictionaries), but my problem starts where that help ends, as can be seen in Done above.

**Update**
The above code works except the last line.

```
persons = set(Person.objects.values_list('name', flat=True).order_by('name'))
persons
{'Alf', 'Beauty'}
available_fruit = set(Fruit.objects.values_list('name', flat=True).order_by('name'))
available_fruit
{'Banana', 'Cape Gooseberry', 'Date', 'Apple', 'Eggplant'}
fruit_in_diet = set(Diet.objects.filter(person_id=1).values_list('fruit_id', flat=True).order_by('fruit_id'))
fruit_in_diet
{1, 2, 4, 5}

But, the difference between the two sets:
missing_fruit = available_fruit - fruit_in_diet
missing_fruit
{'Banana', 'Cape Gooseberry', 'Date', 'Apple', 'Eggplant'}

Same thing with the 2nd person, the difference between the two sets:
fruit_in_diet = set(Diet.objects.filter(person_id=2).values_list('fruit_id', flat=True).order_by('fruit_id'))
fruit_in_diet
{1, 3, 5}

missing_fruit = available_fruit - fruit_in_diet
missing_fruit
{'Banana', 'Cape Gooseberry', 'Date', 'Apple', 'Eggplant'}

I do not understand why this is happening.
If it could work, I would need help on how to loop over the persons rather than specify them as done in these examples.
```

Only the missing_fruit line is not providing the expected answer.

I hope this is my last post on the problem. The missing_fruit line didn't work because it was trying to calculate a difference between a set of string and one of integers. I have now used ids for persons and available_fruit and it works.

Here is the code:

```
persons = set(Person.objects.values_list('id', flat=True).order_by('id'))
```

persons
{1, 2}

available_fruit = set(Fruit.objects.values_list('id', flat=True).order_by('id'))
available_fruit
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5'}

fruit_in_diet = set(Diet.objects.filter(person_id=1).values_list('fruit_id', flat=True).order_by('fruit_id'))
fruit_in_diet
{1, 2, 4, 5}

missing_fruit = available_fruit - fruit_in_diet
missing_fruit
{3}

fruit_in_diet = set(Diet.objects.filter(person_id=2).values_list('fruit_id', flat=True).order_by('fruit_id'))
fruit_in_diet
{1, 3, 5}

missing_fruit = available_fruit - fruit_in_diet
missing_fruit
{2,4}

I  would like to be able to consolidate and display the results as follows

Person      Missing Fruit
Alf         Cape GooseBerry
Beauty      Banana, Date

Can someone please help me with the code to do the looping and then displaying the results as above.

Comment: This site is best used once you have a specific problem that you can't figure out, general questions asking for guidance doesn't fit with SO's objectives.

Comment: This is not a general question. It is a specific problem. What use will it be complicating it more than it is?

Comment: In the actual situation, instead of 5 fruits, I have 30 focus areas and instead of 2 persons, I have hundreds of thousands in over 800 companies! What good does that extra information do in explaining what the actual problem as articulated is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer actually does not even need code to explain it. The first and main priority was to find out whether there were any fruits each of the persons did not take.

Using distinct() and specifying the fruit and person fields produces distinct combinations of person and fruit and if these are less that the expected, (the fruit types * number of people) then some fruit(s) were not taken by some person.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#distinct

Good thing I am on PostgreSQL!

Answer (score 0):

To get the missing fruits for each person, we can use a list of *all* possible fruits in the database and remove each fruit that exists for the person as a `Diet` row in the database.

So that we can render the data in an HTML template, we'll write our missing fruit logic inside of a `view`:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial03/

```py
# views.py
from collections import defaultdict
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Diet, Fruit, Person

def missing_from_diet_list(request):
    # All of the Fruits in the database
    available_fruit = Fruit.objects.order_by("name")

    # All of the Diet objects in the database, with "Person" and "Fruit" joined in a
    # single query, ordered by each Diet's person_id field.
    diets = Diet.objects.select_related("person", "fruit").order_by("person__name")

    # We can use a collections.defaultdict datatype that starts with the full set of
    # possible fruits and removes any Fruit instances that the Person already has in
    # their Diet.
    missing_fruit_map = defaultdict(lambda: set(available_fruit))
    for diet in diets:
        person = diet.person  # Used as the dictionary key
        fruit = diet.fruit  # Removed from the set of available_fruit for the person
        missing_fruit_map[person].remove(fruit)

    # To make the missing fruit data easier to work with in the template, we'll rebuild
    # the missing_fruit_map object as a list of tuples so that it can be sorted by name.
    for person, fruits in missing_fruit_map.items():
        missing_fruit_map[person] = sorted(fruits, key=lambda fruit: fruit.name)

    missing_fruit_table = sorted(missing_fruit_map.items(), key=lambda item: item[0].name)

    return render(
        request,
        "missing_fruit.html",
        {"missing_fruit_table": missing_fruit_table},
    )
```

*To learn how `defaultdict` works, you can read more about it [here in the python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).*

Next, we'll create the `missing_fruit.html` file that gets rendered by our view:

```html
<html>
<head><title>Fruits Missing from People's Diets</title></head>
<body>

    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Person</th>
                <th>Missing Fruits</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for person, missing_fruits in people_with_missing_fruit.items %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ person.name }}</td>
                <td>
                    <ol>
                        {% for fruit in missing_fruits %}
                        <li>{{ fruit.name }}</li>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </ol>
                </td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, Damon. Wow. Let's see in a couple of hours.

Comment: Hi @damon! I am getting a KeyError (<Fruit: Apple> which Traceback references to the code missing_fruit_map[person].remove(fruit). In the Local vars the missing_fruit_map correctly reflects {<Person: Alf>: {<Fruit: Cape Gooseberry>}} - the only fruit missing from Alf's diet. Maybe because of the error, it doesn't seem to move on to the second person, Beauty.

Comment: This means either there are duplicates in your Diet table (the same fruit existing 2x or more for the same person), or that not all of the fruits exist in the `Fruit` table. Can you post how your 3 models are implemented?

Comment: Yes @damon, there are deliberate duplications(diets 1-4 and 8-11). That's why my first thoughts were of sets - I would like the duplications to be treated as single instances for each person. Knowing that the duplications are deliberate, I think you are close to solving the problem as it is. We can arrange to chat outside of the platform if you want to but I think the info is sufficient for resolution of the problem.